# create a wave scatter diagram

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I'm trying to recreate the figure attached to this message. I have a database of wave recordings at a specific location for 1 year. The goal is to create a probability of occurrence based on the wave period and significant wave height.

[image: wave scatter diagram]

I managed to plot the contour, but unfortunately, I can't create a grid like the figure with the occurrence values and the corresponding colors on the colorbar. I tried using the annotate function, but it fills the figure with too many values. I am attaching what I obtained with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# Chemin vers le fichier CSV
file = 'Candhis_03404_2022_arch.csv'

# Lecture du fichier CSV
donnees = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=';')

donnees['H13D'] = donnees['H13D'].replace(999.999, pd.NA)
donnees['TH13D'] = donnees['TH13D'].replace(999.999, pd.NA)
donnees= donnees.dropna(subset=['H13D', 'TH13D'])


H13D=donnees['H13D']
TH13D=donnees['TH13D']


data_croisement=pd.crosstab(H13D,TH13D,margins=False)


total_occurences=np.sum(data_croisement.sum(axis=0))

prob_occurence_rows=(data_croisement/total_occurences)*100

H_values = np.sort(donnees['H13D'].unique())
T_values = np.sort(donnees['TH13D'].unique())
T, H = np.meshgrid(T_values, H_values)

# Création du contour plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
contour = plt.contourf(T, H, prob_occurence_rows, cmap='coolwarm')
plt.colorbar(contour, label='Probabilité d\'occurences(%)')
plt.xlabel('Période significative (s)')
plt.ylabel('Hauteur significative (m)')
plt.title('Contour plot du tableau de contingence')

""" for i in range(len(H_values)):
    for j in range(len(T_values)):
       plt.annotate(f'{prob_occurence_rows.iloc[i, j]}', xy=(T_values[j], H_values[i]), ha='center', va='center') """
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[The image I obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kFZV.png)

Comment: You have included only one image. Is this the figure you are trying to recreate or the one that you got with the code that you shared?

Comment: what are the contents of this file: `file = 'Candhis_03404_2022_arch.csv'` ?

Comment: @hb20007 I modified my edit and I uploaded the figure I obtained.
 I can't upload the data, but on the other hand, you can access the data on this website :( https://candhis.cerema.fr/_public_/campagne.php). The data is open access you just have to fill the form.